# Using fgets and linked lists

Tags: c, linked-list, fgets, singly-linked-list

I am trying to get user input from fgets() and save the entry into a linked list but it isn't saving the entry into the linked lists, but if I directly put it in the call, it does. ex. `add_to_list(&list, "hello");` How do use fgets to save into a character array (called word), which I can stick into add_to_list call?

```
    void
    add_to_list(struct linked_list *list, char *x)
    {
        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
        n->data = x;
        n->next = NULL;
        if (list->head == NULL)
            list->head = n;
        if (list->tail != NULL)
            list->tail->next = n;
        list->tail = n;
    }

    int
    main(void)
    {
        struct linked_list list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
        char word[50];

        do {
            printf("Enter string: ");
            fgets(word, 50, stdin)
            add_to_list(&list, word);
        } while (word[0] != '\n');

        //add_to_list(&list, "hello");
        print_list_rec(&list);
        free_list(&list);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are re-using the same buffer over and over. Insert a `strdup`, just about anywhere.

Comment: ^ Yep, strdup is what you're looking for here.  Just remember that you'll need to free the memory you allocated.

Comment: You know that `!= NULL` in conditionals is useless clutter, and `!` is shorter and easier on the eye than `== NULL`?

Comment: ^ Some people like to see the != NULL.  It doesn't change the resulting program, and is more a personal taste thing.  Also, it's completely unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
n->data = x;
```

This statement assigns the pointer to the buffer to the `data` pointer of the list. However, this is the same pointer in all calls. Moreover, the buffer is in the automatic storage, because `word` is a local variable.

In order to fix this problem you need to add copying of the string into dynamically allocated buffers. Use `strlen` to decide how much memory you need, `strcpy` to copy the data, and don't forget to free the string after you are done with the struct.

```
size_t len = strlen(x);
n->data = malloc(len+1);
strcpy(n->data, x);
```

This goes inside `free_list`:

```
free(n->data);
free(n);
```